# Why does people seem transparent in this video

Tags: compression

People seem transparent in that video. What does explain that?

I posted on the Physics community, believing that it was related to some optical effect. But I've been told that it may be related to video compression.

https://www.instagram.com/p/BmJDU1Snd1O/?utm_source=ig_share_sheet&igshid=1qwkhrbxglb3q

Comment: What did I just watch?

Comment: That's a minor celebrity known as a (kinda) funny soccer commentator doing the so called (by not much people) "the pidgeon dance".